# iOS User Interface - How is this User Interface being implemented in the YouTube and Facebook apps

Tags: ios, user-interface

I've noticed a number of apps switching to the following User Interface format as a means to maximize the amount of space available to the user's currently selected view controller and also elegantly display a list of options/view controllers for the user to choose from.

Example - The YouTube app:

[image] [image]

I am hoping for suggestions on how to emulate this style of "menu" /UI - Specific examples/tutorials would be awesome, but I'd also be grateful for suggestions on what general direction I should be working towards

**Here's what I have broken this down to so far:**

1. Bar Button item in UINavigationController when tapped loads a container
2. The container has a UITableView in it.
3. When a row is tapped, this somehow affects the "main" view controller that the user sees - i.e. The view controller that is currently on screen becomes the one that the user just tapped.

**I am unsure if:**

1. The above breakdown is correct?
2. How to create the nice slide in transition that one gets when they tap the left bar button item in the navigation controller
3. How to then make the view controller (I am assuming of course that I would tie each row in the "menu" to a specific view controller) the "main" view controller on screen.

Thank you in advance for your time!

P.S. I intend to target iOS 6.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several open-source controls on github:

https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController
https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels
https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck

I don't think it worths to spend time and re-invent the wheel :).

Comment: Thank you! JASidePanels looks like exactly what I am looking for! Have a great one!

Answer (score 4):

The Best i know, like Facebook, youtube app.

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jasidepanels

Comment: I mentioned this control in my list ;)

Comment: Tom - I upvoted you but ended up select kovpas's answer since he included the same in his response and was the first to my aid :) Thank you very much in any case!